# Ensuring sequential disposing of multiple IDisposables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have two `IDisposables` that I need to have disposed in sequential order.  The ordering is important  since the first `IDisposable` kills an Rx subscription that is relying on a service that will be killed by the second `IDisposable`.  This is within a Windows Forms application where the subscription of the `IObservable` needs to happen on a different thread but the observing and disposing needs to happen on the UI thread. (Actually, I don't care if the disposing happens on the UI thread as long as the order is ensured.) So, in code I have roughly the following (once reduced):

```
SomeService = new DisposableService();
Subscription = Foo(someService).SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).ObserveOn(theForm).Subscribe(...)
```

On a number of UI events I need to dispose of both of these in order (Subscription and then SomeService).  To do this I have tried using Rx's `CompositeDisposable` in addition to the `ContextDisposable` to provide serial disposing on the same thread:

```
_Disposable = new CompositeDisposable(new[] {                     
    new ContextDisposable(WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current, Subscription),                     
    new ContextDisposable(WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current, SomeService)});
```

The above does not work however.  Based on my logging `_Disposable` and the `ContextDisposable` for `SomeService` are called on the same thread but the `ContextDisposable` is still occurring on a different thread concurent with the service being disposed (and thus resulting in race conditions and NPEs).

I've only been programming C# for a couple of weeks and so I'm sure the problem is my misunderstanding of how contexts and dispatchers work.  What is the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just dispose of both in the same thread?  If you synchronize the dispose method and all the other methods, you can control the ordering yourself.  If you have to consume from one thread and dispose in another you need to make all your consumers threadsafe and check if its been disposed or not before you do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you can control which thread disposes what. Who subscribes on which thread doesn't matter.  Look at this example

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReactiveTest rx1 = null;
        ReactiveTest rx2 = null;

        var thread1 = new Thread(() => rx1 = new ReactiveTest());
        var thread2 = new Thread(() => rx2 = new ReactiveTest());

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();

        rx1.Dispose();
        rx2.Dispose();
    }
}

public class ReactiveTest : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable _timerObservable;

    private object _lock = new object();

    public ReactiveTest()
    {
        _timerObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)).Subscribe(i => 
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _timerObservable.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - DISPOSING", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
[14] - 0
[7] - 0
[15] - 1
[7] - 1
[14] - 2
[15] - 2
[10] - DISPOSING
[10] - DISPOSING
```

You can see we subscribed on two seperate threads, then disposed on a third.  I only locked the dispose in case you had something threadsafe that needs to happen in the subscription. In this example it's unnecessary really.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense and your code behaves as I would expect it to.  I'm seeing different behavior in my app though with regards to what thread subscriptions are being disposed on.  After taking a second look I think my problem may be related to my use of `Publish` and `RefCount`.  My disposing simply will reduce the ref count and the "real" disposing will take place on a different thread as that count hits 0.  Race conditions then occur because the `RefCount` does it thing on a different thread while my second dispose on the service is firing.

Comment: Turns out that `RefCount` wasn't the culprit after all.  It has to do with my use of `SubscribeOn` but I still haven't figured out how to workaround it.  I posted a new question with working code showing the problem I'm facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131306/controlling-what-thread-an-rx-subscription-is-disposed-on-after-subscribedon-has

Answer (score 0):

[SubscribeOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.subscribeon(v=vs.103).aspx) schedules the calls to both `Subscribe` and `Dispose`.  Therefore, calling `Dispose` on your *Subscription* variable, regardless of whether execution is currently on the UI thread or not, results in the subscription being scheduled for disposal by `NewThreadScheduler.Default`.

It's almost never a good idea to use `SubscribeOn`; however, in your case you're claiming that it solves 50% of your problem - and that's 50% more than most uses I've seen - so I must question whether or not you actually need the subscription to execute on a background thread in the first place.  It's awfully expensive to create a brand new thread and then invoke a method on it, compared to just calling a method on the UI thread directly, if all the method does is begin some asynchronous work such as sending a network request or reading a file.  Perhaps if computing a network message to be sent is proven to be overly time-consuming, then using `SubscribeOn` may be correct; although, of course, only if you want disposal scheduled as well.

If the subscription to your observable must execute on a background thread, yet disposal must remain free-threaded, then consider using the following operator instead (untested).

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
  public static IObservable<TSource> SubscribeOn<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    bool doNotScheduleDisposal, 
    IScheduler scheduler)
  {
    if (!doNotScheduleDisposal)
    {
      return source.SubscribeOn(scheduler);
    }

    return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
      {
        // Implementation is based on that of the native SubscribeOn operator in Rx
        var s = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var d = new SerialDisposable();
        d.Disposable = s;
        s.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(() =>
        {
          d.Disposable = source.SubscribeSafe(observer);
        });
        return d;
      });
  }
}
```