# Controlling what thread an Rx subscription is Disposed on after SubscribedOn has been used

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a Rx subscription that I `SubscribeOn` with a different thread to prevent it from blocking.  However, I want the disposal of that subscription to block due to resource management issues.  I have not been able to figure out how to accomplish this within the context of either a console app or a winforms app (I have both use cases).  Below is working code of a reduced case that simulates what I am doing:

```
internal class Program
{

    private static void Log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] " + msg, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var foo = Observable.Create<long>(obs =>
            {
                Log("Subscribing starting.. this will take a few seconds..");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                var sub =
                    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                              .Do(_ => Log("I am polling..."))
                              .Subscribe(obs);
                return Disposable.Create(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                        sub.Dispose();
                        Log("Disposing is really done now!");
                    });
            });

        Log("I am subscribing..");
        var disp = foo.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(i => Log("Processing " + i.ToString()));
        Log("I have returned from subscribing...");

        // SC.Current is null in a ConsoleApp :/  Can I get a SC that uses my current thread?
        //var dispSynced = new ContextDisposable(SynchronizationContext.Current, disp);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Log("I'm going to dispose...");
        //dispSynced.Dispose();
        disp.Dispose();
        Log("Disposed has returned...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When the above is ran I get:

```
[10] I am subscribing..
[10] I have returned from subscribing...
[11] Subscribing starting.. this will take a few seconds..
[6] I am polling...
[6] Processing 0
[6] I am polling...
[6] Processing 1
[10] I'm going to dispose...
[10] Disposed has returned...
[13] I am polling...
[6] I am polling...
[13] I am polling...
[14] Disposing is really done now!
```

So, all I'm trying to do is to have `[10] Disposed has returned...` be the last line printed indicating that the Dispose call is blocking.

The `ContextDisposable` that Rx ships with seems ideal for my use case but I don't know how to get a `SynchronizationContext` representing my current thread.  Is there a way I can use `ContextDisposable` to do what I want or do I need a totally different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for SubscribeOn it looks like the dispose function will be scheduled on the specified scheduler. Try something like this:

```
private static IObservable<long> GetObservable(IScheduler scheduler)
{
  return Observable.Create<long>(obs =>
  {
    var disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    disposables.Add(
      Disposable.Create(() =>
      {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        Log("Disposing is really done now!");
      }));

    disposables.Add(
      scheduler.Schedule(() =>
      {
        Log("Subscribing starting.. this will take a few seconds..");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        disposables.Add(
          Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Do(_ => Log("I am polling...")).Subscribe(obs));
      }));

    return disposables;
  });


private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var foo = GetObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);

  Log("I am subscribing..");
  var disp = foo.Subscribe(i => Log("Processing " + i.ToString()));
  Log("I have returned from subscribing...");

  // SC.Current is null in a ConsoleApp :/  Can I get a SC that uses my current thread?
  //var dispSynced = new ContextDisposable(SynchronizationContext.Current, disp);
  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  Log("I'm going to dispose...");
  //dispSynced.Dispose();
  disp.Dispose();
  Log("Disposed has returned...");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(starting from scratch - there's another way!)

This was an interesting thing to look into - truth be told, I've never had a need for this before, but there's an observable extension `Observable.Synchronize`:

This makes blocking quite trivial, although I'm not 100% sure this will apply to your use case...regardless, here's a modified main using this approach:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sync = new object();
    var foo = Observable.CreateWithDisposable<long>(obs =>
    {
        Log("Subscribing starting.. this will take a few seconds..");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        var sub = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                        .Do(_ => Log("I am polling..."))
                        .Synchronize(sync)
                        .Subscribe(obs);
        return Disposable.Create(
            () =>
                {
                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                        sub.Dispose();
                        Log("Disposing is really done now!");                                
                    }
                });
    });

    Log("I am subscribing..");
    var disp = foo
        .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
        .Subscribe(i => Log("Processing " + i));

    Log("I have returned from subscribing...");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Log("I'm going to dispose...");
    disp.Dispose();
    Log("Disposed has returned...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!  I tried your custom class in conjunction with `ContextDisposable` and it didn't block... in fact the method returned but it never really stopped the action (polling).  My guess is that the problem is related to the use of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` since, from what I can tell, that is supposed to be used in the context of a GUI app (I had to add a reference to `Windows.Base`.)  I'm totally new to c# so I have no idea really though.

Comment: @BenMabey The Dispatcher class is not *strictly* tied to GUI apps - it's more aligned with the concept of a message pump, in my opinion..that said, I've added the slightly modified Main() method I used to test - (hit send too soon) - maybe I'm misreading what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BenMabey Ahh, I get what you're trying to do now...ok, lemme rethink this.

Comment: That's an interesting use of `Syncronize` and I thought it would work but when I ran your code I still see polling after the Dispose call has returned. My output: https://gist.github.com/0de0f80700c014888924

Comment: @BenMabey I did see that last trailing poll...and I think I know why: basically, you've got that last queued up poll waiting to enter the critical section (which is acquired by the disposer). I suppose you could alter the subscriber slightly such that it checks some "hey, we're still going" variable, invalidated in the dispose...can you confirm that it's always just the one trailing poll?

Comment: @BenMabey Hahaha...comment out the "Do" line (alternatively, move the Synchronize call above the Do). It's not actually passing that last along to the observer, it's because the Do is outside of the Synchronized block. :)